# SwitchView for each UITableViewcell in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have added a switchview as an accessory view to the UItableviewcell, i have 5 entries in the table ie., 5 cells and switches for them in that row.. I have given each switch a tag value which is equal to indexpath.row (so 1st switch is 0, 2nd is 1 ... and 5th switch is 4)

---

```
UISwitch *switchView = [[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
cell.accessoryView = switchView;
[switchView setOn:NO animated:NO];
[switchView setTag:indexPath.row];
```

I have given a target method for the switch, the target method gets called when the value of switch is changed..

```
[switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(switchTimer:)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

In this target method based on the change in event of the Switch I'm trying to building an array with count equal to the number of switches..
Eg: If Switch 0 and 3 are ON and Switch 1,2,4 are OFF, the array would look something like this

```
A = {"ON","OFF","OFF","ON","OFF"}
```

The following is the method which I'm using to achieve this:

```
-(void)switchTimer:(UISwitch *)senderSwitch{
       NSLog(@"Sender Switch Tag is %d",senderSwitch.tag);

       for(int i=0;i<[array_Timers count];i++){//Start for loop

         senderSwitch.tag = i;

         if(senderSwitch.on){
               NSLog(@"%@ is ON",[array_Timers objectAtIndex:i]);
               //Here I add an object to the array with value "ON"

         }
         else{
               NSLog(@"%@ is OFF",[array_Timers objectAtIndex:i]);
              //Here I add an object to the array with value "OFF"
         }

     }//End for loop
}
```

The problem is every time a switch gets on, say switch 2 (with tag 1) all the switches will get the tag value 1, even if i iterate over all the switches with the help of their tag values. I want to know the status of all switches even when only 1 switch's value gets changed.. but that's not happening, all the switches get tag value 1 and i get an array like this

```
A = {"ON","ON","ON","ON","ON"}//when switch 2 is ON

A = {"OFF","OFF","OFF","OFF","OFF"}//when switch 2 is OFF
```

Can someone please help me out finding what the issue is?
Thanks in advance

EDIT : the complete cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell  *cell = [timersTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;


if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    UISwitch *switchView = [[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    cell.accessoryView = switchView;
    [switchView setOn:NO animated:NO];
    [switchView setTag:indexPath.row];
    [switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(switchTimer:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [switchView release];


    UIView *v = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = v;

}
UserTimer *usertimer = [array_Timers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//irrelevant here
[cell.textLabel setText:usertimer.alias];


return cell;
```

}

Comment: This is because you checking `if(senderSwitch.on)` in the loop. If this button is on all elements in the array become `ON` and vice versa.

Comment: Forgive me If I'm wrong I've started with Objective C 3 months ago, my doubt is, if each row has its own allocated switch, with one switch pointer (or a reference) i can skim through all the switches based on their assigned tag values and have a check on the status of the switch..and why shouldn't one use a for loop to do this?

Comment: Show us your cellForRowAtIndexPath. Cell reuse could be causing all kinds of problems for you...

Comment: @user2728987 You can iterate through all switches by their assigned tag. But not by `senderSwitch.tag = i;`, this only changes the tag of `senderSwitch` not give the reference to the switch with tag `i`.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't know that it shouldn't be done that way. Thanks for the help..(on a lighter note logically it should be possible -_-)

Comment: @user2728987 I see a cell reuse bug in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. You could probably reproduce the bug if you scroll some of your cells off the table view and then back on. You should set the tag every time its called. Not just when the cell is first created.

Comment: @user2728987 Also, you're setting the cell's selectionStyle on a nil cell when you don't have any cells to dequeue. That line should be inside of the "new cell" if block.

Comment: Pardon me I'm still trying to understand your first comment.. "You should set the tag very time it is called"  Where do I do that? My understanding is a cell should be given a tag when it gets created, why do we have to set it again?

Comment: @CrimsonChris agreed with the second comment you're right, I should set the selection style inside, I'm sorry I overlooked it when I was coding

Comment: @user2728987 Example: when a cell that was first created for index 0 gets reused for index 7, its tag will still be 0. Try adding more cells than will fit the tableview at any one time. Then scroll through them a couple times and you should see this behavior.

Comment: @CrimsonChris Yes you're correct, for rows more than 10 or something, switches turn on/off behave in a weird way..now i know why i should set the tag everytime it is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using the for loop, values of the switches are getting change. so you don't need to use for loop here. instead you can just replace the object at the index of your current switch.

```
-(void)switchTimer:(UISwitch *)senderSwitch {
    NSString *currentValue = @"";
    NSInteger index = senderSwitch.tag;
    if(senderSwitch.on){
        currentValue = @"ON";
    }
    else {
        currentValue = @"OFF";
    }

    [array_Timers replaceObjectAtIndex: index withObject: currentValue];
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, that's completely right I don't have to iterate over again  and again. That's a good solution

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the status of all switches even when only 1 switch's value gets changed try this,

```
-(void)switchTimer:(UISwitch *)senderSwitch{
       NSLog(@"Sender Switch Tag is %d",senderSwitch.tag);

       for(int i=0;i<[array_Timers count];i++){//Start for loop
         NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
         UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
         UISwitch *switch = (UISwitch *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row];

         if(switch.on){
               NSLog(@"%@ is ON",[array_Timers objectAtIndex:i]);
               //Here I add an object to the array with value "ON"

         }
         else{
               NSLog(@"%@ is OFF",[array_Timers objectAtIndex:i]);
              //Here I add an object to the array with value "OFF"
         }

     }//End for loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is: primarily initialise the Array with the Values of OFF, before the Table gets loaded . For Ex :

```
-(Void) ViewDidLoad {
   array_Timers = [NSArray alloc]... // Add the Objects .
}
```

In the UITableView Delegate :*(don't try to set Tag as 0 to any elements )*

```
UISwitch *switchView = [[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
cell.accessoryView = switchView;
[switchView setOn:NO animated:NO];
[switchView setTag:indexPath.row+25]; //don't try to set Tag as 0 to any elements 
[switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(switchTimer:)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Then just replace with the values according to the events

```
-(void)switchTimer:(UISwitch *)senderSwitch{
      [array_Timers replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[[NSNumber numberWithBool:senderSwitch - 25]];

NSLog (@" Values %@", array_Timers );
}
```

Comment: Is the +25 to avoid mistaking a switch with an unset tag and the 0th switch?

Comment: This didn't work well I got an Array out of range exception: reason is that the array index and tags are related. The element at array index 0, will be the name of the row which has a switch with tag 0

-------------------------------------------------
MasterComputer        switch(OFF/ON)
-------------------------------------------------

MasterComputer would be an element with index 0 in the array I'm using to label the cell

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
-(void)switchTimer:(UISwitch *)senderSwitch{
   NSLog(@"Sender Switch Tag is %d",senderSwitch.tag);

   for (UISwitch *mySwitch in switchesArray) {

     if(mySwitch.on){
           NSLog(@"%@ is ON",mySwitch);
           //Here I add an object to the array with value "ON"

     }
     else{
           NSLog(@"%@ is OFF",mySwitch);
          //Here I add an object to the array with value "OFF"
     }

 }//End for loop
```

Note - If you are reusing your switches and the order in array_Timers is not consistent with the order in your table view, you should sort your switches by tag first.